# How can I make images of an old Magento work with a fresh installation (with the old db attached)?

Tags: magento2, product-images, migration, data-migration, database-connection

I dont know how exactly to put it in words, so heres my problem

I have an old corrupted Magento server (2.3). I have installed a fresh Magento (2.3) and used the sql dump from the old one, the products and everything else works fine. I also copied /media folder from the old server to the new installation, same path/directory. Doing this doesn't show up the images in my fresh Magento site.

Can you tell me how I can make this work? I just need the data to show up completely on the new site, not concerned with rebuilding the site or other content than products.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put your images here at **pub\media\wysiwyg**

and then run this commands

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```